# does robocopy kill files while mirroring if read error?

Tags: windows, script, robocopy

my params is `/mir /copyall /dcopy:t /z /v /tee /eta /unilog+ /mt:32 /r:3 /w:30`

for example, some copying finishes ok
so, is read error "equal" no-file? will robocopy delete file at destination dir if it can't read source, at next run?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. If it get's an error it tries to copy it again for 3x more times and if robocopy can't copy that file at all it stops the whole copying process at that point.

Comment: > ...it stops the whole copying process...
@ricardo-bohner if the 1st file of many Gb is broken, only files processed in /r:3 * /w:30 = 150seconds (in others /mt:32 threads) will copied, right?

Comment: No if it can't copy a file I think it stops all sequencial copying. If the problem is in a junction (link) you can try /XJ to bypass this....

Comment: If you can't copy a file you can also put it in a exclusion list with /xf MyProblemFile.exe. I always had problems with a hidden file in onedrive that looks like this: ".349C9593-D756-4E56-1D6E-42412F2A3075" I think it is blocked or something, and I had to put it in the exclusion list when I backup onedrive with robocopy...